# WebView2 icon not visible in Toolbox (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, webview2

I try to use WebView2 component in WinForm application in C#. But I have a problem to install WebView2 component to Visual Studio. I use Windows 10.

I follow the [Microsoft instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms#step-4---install-the-webview2-sdk) but **the problem is, that the WebView2 icon does not appear in the Toolbox**.

- I have tried Visual Studio 2017 and 2022
- I have tried several WebView2 versions
- I have updated Edge and installed "Canary"
- I have tried .NET Framework 4.7.2 and 4.8
- I have rebooted computer (several
  times)

but no result.

After installation of WebView2 by NuGet, in the project folder I see subfolder `packages\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.1.0.2151.40`

I have tried to add icon manually:
right-click on Toolbox -> Choose items  - in the list there is NO WebView2, therefore I click *Browse* and try to use ANY of dll's in the folder packages\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.1.0.2151.40\lib\net45 (or netcoreapp3.0). The result is error: *There are no components in ...dll that can be placed on the toolbox*

Strange thing: I have installed WebView2 on the same computer some 2 years ago. It was pain, but it worked. I used it for project in Visual Studio 2017 C# WinForm apllication. If I open the old project again, it works, I am able to rebuild the project, but in the Toolbox  is no WebView2 icon.

**Any idea what to do?
Or is there some other (similar) component?**

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I have found, that I can not add ANY new component to my project. Visual Studio (probably any version) SOMETIMES does not like to have sharp character (#) in path.

My project folder is "D:\Source\C#\Project..." and that was the problem. I renamed it to "D:\Source\cSharp\Project..." and everything is fine.

Comment: Yeah it's because it treats path like urls where `#` indicates a 'fragment', can be annoying, but good you found out.